# Dataset of allergies

Tags: data-request, medical

I'm looking for a dataset containing the following:

- for each country, for each allergy types, number of humans affected by the allergy.
- if possible, break down per gender and age.

Comment: Have you searched through [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=allergy+world+population) for relevant studies?

Answer (score 2):

A list of statistics is available for U.S. persons:

- Medical treatment triggered by [allergies and hay fever](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/allergies.htm).
- Allergy by [age and ethnicity](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/hdi.htm) for 1998-2012 (specifically at 205.207.175.93/HDI/TableViewer/tableView.aspx?ReportId=59)

An interesting [related article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23256652) about the need for more data on allergy prevalence in developing nations may be informative.